# Flutter How to Check Location Change using geolocator pacakge?

Tags: flutter

I have to display popup message when my location is changed using geolocator package, So how i can do this?

I have to display message when my location is changed?

Comment: If your question how to display the popup, or how to get notified with the location changes?

Comment: i have to display message when my location is changed

Comment: can you clarify how the message should be shown?  Is it just a text field with the current location?  Is there a image of what you want to do?

Comment: in alert dialog

Comment: if your question is about to update screen in alert dialog. You can use statefull builder widget as a content of alert dialog.if  not you need to more specific that explains your question.

Answer (score 0):

take a look this example, just edit it according to your need.

```
 showDialog(context: Get.context!, builder: (ctx){
      return AlertDialog(
        content: StatefulBuilder(builder: (ctx,stater){

          late Position yourLatLngLocation;
          StreamSubscription<Position> positionStream = Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: locationSettings).listen(
    (Position? position) {
      stater((){
        yourLatLngLocation = position; 
      });
       
    });

    return YourMapView(yourLatLngLocation);
        }
        ) ,
      );
    });
```

Comment: please can you give me more details about locationSettings.